# Sysrq keeps taking screen shots

Tags: linux, magic-sysrq

I have enabled SysRq in the kernel like this:

```
$su
#echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

and confirmed that it worked.

<kbd>Fn-F1</kbd> is my SysRq key, but every time I press <kbd>Alt-Fn-F1</kbd> and any other letter that should go here like `t` it doesn't work. It just takes a screenshot. Even pressing `r` takes a screenshot.

It this common? How do I get around this? I'm using Fedora 16

Comment: Did you follow the tips on [Magic SysRq Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) ?

Comment: Are you releasing `Fn` (and `Alt` and `F1`) before you press `t`? If you're not, you may be pressing `Fn+t` instead. And what do you mean by “takes a screenshot”? That sounds like a software thing, triggered by pressing a key, so what key would trigger a screenshot in your setup?

Comment: I press Alt then Fn then F1 then t, in that order holding down each preceding key until the sequence is complete

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned it yet, but it may be relevant that on almost all keyboards I have seen, `SysRq` shares a physical key with `PrintScreen`, and the `Fn` key may be required to get `SysRq` on laptops.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a laptop which requires you to press an Fn key to activate the Sysrq key then press Alt-Fn-Sysrqkey let go of Fn then press the required key or key combo

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid screenshot, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>sysRq</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>.

E.g., you would have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, release <kbd>Fn</kbd> and then press M to show the memory usage.